# DataContract, default DataMember value

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract, datamember

Is there a way to choose default values of attributes that are not in the xml file during deserialization?
If the `mAge` attribute is not present in the xml file, I want to use a default value of 18.  Is it possible ?

```
[DataContract]
public class Person 
{
    public Person ()
    {
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string mName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Age")]
    public int mAge { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Single")]
    public bool mIsSingle { get; set; }
};
```

Edit to put the answer.

```
[DataContract]
public class Person 
{
    public Person ()
    {
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string mName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Age")]
    public int? mAge { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Single")]
    public bool? mIsSingle { get; set; }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserialized(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext c)
    {
        mAge = (mAge == null ? 18 : mAge); // 18 is the default value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [[OnDeserialized]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx)

> Use the OnDeserializedAttribute **when you need to fix values on a
>   deserialized object after it has been deserialized** and before the
>   graph is returned.

```
[DataContract]
 public class Person 
  {
    public Person ()
    {
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string mName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Age")]
    public int mAge { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Single")]
    public bool mIsSingle { get; set; }



    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserialized(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext c)
    {
      mAge = (mAge == 0) ?18:mAge;
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT: From your Comments**

For bool or int you can use [nullable bool and nullable int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) 
 so if these age and Single attributes are missing in xml file then they will be null as well.

here is quick sample I prepared

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using MySpace;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System;
namespace MySpace
{

 [DataContract]
 public class Person 
  {
    public Person ()
    {
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string mName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Age")]
    public int? mAge { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Single")]
    public bool? mIsSingle { get; set; }



    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserialized(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext c)
    {
      mAge =  (mAge == null ? 18 : mAge);
    }
  }
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
  [OperationContract]
  Person Method(Person dd);
}

public class Service : IService
{
  public Person Method(Person dd)
  {
    return dd;
  }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string Url = "http://localhost:8000/";
    Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, Url);
    host.Open();
    ChannelFactory<IService> fac = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding);
    fac.Open();
    IService proxy = fac.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(Url));
    Person d = new Person();
    d.mName = "BuzBuza";

    Console.WriteLine("Data before calling service " + (d.mAge == null ? " null " : d.mAge.Value.ToString()));
    Console.WriteLine("Data before calling service " + (d.mIsSingle == null ? "null" : d.mIsSingle.Value.ToString()));
    d = proxy.Method(d);
    fac.Close();
    host.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Data after calling service " + (d.mAge == null ? " null " : d.mAge.Value.ToString()));
    Console.WriteLine("Data after calling service " + (d.mIsSingle == null ? "null" : d.mIsSingle.Value.ToString()));

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: I can use your answer if I want to override the value of an object, because when the reference is set to null I know that the attribut is not present in the xml File. But how can I know if a boolean or an int attribut is present in the xml file ? If the value for a bolean is set to false or an int is set to 0. I can't distingue beetwen unseted attribut and attribut seted to default c# value.

Comment: As deserilization will try to set default values for missing data in a given structure so your only option is to check for valid values eg as I updated my answer and checking for if age mAge == 0 then set your value.

Comment: You can use nullable types to get around int and null ,plz check my updated ans

Comment: Thks you, your answer solve my issue. Using nullable types and System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserialized function isbrilliant idea. My post is edited to give the answers.

Answer (score 8):

use [[OnDeserializing()]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

and you set your values BEFORE the deserialization. So there is no check necessary, which could go wrong - what if the mAge was serialized to be 0?

Comment: When you deserialize simple types (e.g. `double`) or structs this is the correct way to go. Before deserialization you set optional fields to some app-specific default (or invalid value, e.g. `double.NaN`). Deserialization will overwrite all values given in the XML file and leave others untouched. After deserialization you cannot distinguish a zero value "set from XML" and a zero value "not being set".

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
[DataContract]
 public class Person 
  {
    public Person ()
    {
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string mName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Age")]
    public int mAge = 18;
    [DataMember(Name = "Single")]
    public bool mIsSingle { get; set; }
  };
```

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792.aspx) page.

Comment: No, this does not work (just tested it). The Deserializer overrides your default value, _even if that value is not present in XML_.