# How to get constructor from server on client side in C#?

Tags: c#, wcf, constructor

On my client side, I want the default C# constructors from my WCF service C# classes. There reason we want to do this is to have the default values from the server side classes on the client side. From the searches I've done, there are 2 ways to go about this:

1. When I need a default instance of the object I make a server call that returns me the default instance
2. I create a client side C# class which inherits from the server side C# class and copy paste the constructor and use this constructor

Is either one of these the "better" option? or is this heavily dependent on how often I would need a new instance of the object?

EDIT: We tried using `[System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserialized]` [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566204/datacontract-default-datamember-value) but it's not working. We are also not using the `DataContract` attribute in our class, we use `ServiceKnownType` instead

Comment: With this approach any client of your WCF will depend on the "proxy" classes provided by you. They cannot use WCF independently. Another point of view  -  having some logic in the constructor not a good idea - maybe you can redesign your classes?

Comment: @Fabio we have default values for our classes that we want to keep. We tried using `[System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserialized]` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566204/datacontract-default-datamember-value) but it's not working. We are not using `DataContract` attribute in our class, we use `ServiceKnownType` instead

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using `OnDeserializing` attribute

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.OnDeserializing]
private void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext ctx)
{
   // Here set your default values
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this too but it didn't work.. I think it's because we're using `[ServiceKnownType]`